# Python 3.5 How do I list classes/functions available in an import package?

Tags: python-3.5

I'm porting all my Python code from 2.7 to 3.5 and keep running into issues where my imported packages don't contain the same classes/functions as they did in 2.7.  I DO NOT want to use one of the methods where you can support both 2.7 and 3x.  I'm dropping 2.7 entirely.

Is there a way to search an imported package for a specific thing or to list the classes/functions in a nested display?

Right now, I'm trying to find the escape_string() function in mysql-connector-python (v8x) but I keep needing something to explore packages.  The docs for the mysql-connector-python package say that it's in mysql.connector.MySQL but there's no such attribute.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the documentation is wrong, I would open an issue with them and also double and triple check that you have installed the correct package.

To list the classes/functions of a module you can use:

```
import os # or whatever
print(list(os.__dict__.keys()))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  This gives me a different output than print(dir(obj)) but I'm not clear on why.  Also, the output doesn't appear to drill down and show the hierarchy of where within the package the element is located.